# Metodo show no funciona en laravel con controlador resource

Tags: laravel

tengo un problemita con con el metodo show de mi controlador.
Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar un unico registro, pero no me reconoce la vista a la que estoy apuntando.

Este es mi metodo donde quiero que me redirija mi vista

```
public function show($id)
    {
        //
        $empresa = User::find($id);
        return view('welcome', ['empresa' => $empresa]);
    }
```

Esta es mi ruta

```
Route::resource('/', 'Users\EmpresaController');
```

esta es mi vista, donde al darle click a la imagen o algo me deberia redireccionar a mi vista welcome.

```
 @foreach($empresas as $empresa)
                <a href="{{url('/',array($empresa->id))}}">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="{{asset('imagenes/empresas/'.$empresa->foto)}}" height="320" width="150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4><a href="#">{{$empresa->name}}</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>pagina web <a target="_blank" href="http://www.bootsnipp.com">www.ejemplo.com</a>.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">15 encuestas</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>    
                @endforeach
```

y este es el mensaje que me sale

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found
```

que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Prueba tu ruta asi :
Route::get('user/{id}', 'NombreController@show');

Comment: Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');

Comment: 'Users\EmpresaController' Users es un directorio donde tengo mi controlador, no tendra algun efecto sobre el que lo guarde en un directorio aparte?

Comment: Tienes que pasarle la ruta exacta donde se encuentra tu controller 

Route::resource('users', 'carpeta/UsersController');

Comment: Route::get('/{id}', 'Users\EmpresaController@show'); de esta forma funciona bien, pero yo quiero que me funcione asi Route::resource('/', 'Users\EmpresaController'); con la ruta resource

Comment: no comprendo, si ya te funciona como te indican para que lo necesitas de otro modo?

Comment: Porque quiero trabajar con rutas resource amigo

Comment: ¿Porque inventar la rueda? De esta manera tambien te deberia funcionar Route::resource('users', 'carpeta/UsersController');

Comment: deberia, pero no me funciona. es por eso que estoy preguntando @Oswuell, yo quiero que funcione con rutas resource, y lo hago de la forma en que me mostraste pero no me funciona

Comment: Nunca te va a funcionar porque esto esta mal Route::resource('/', 'Users\EmpresaController');

Comment: Imprime todas las rutas y las envias para ver

Comment: Ya entendi, cambie el nombre de la url y ya funciono, quedo asi Route::resource('users', 'Users\EmpresaController');. Gracias por los aportes,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto

```
Route::resource('users', 'Users\EmpresaController');
```

Comment: Gracias. me funciono de esa forma, aunque no entiendo porque funciona con 'users' y no asi '/'. pero bueno, ya funciona bien

Comment: Si te sirvió marcarla como bien para que le sirva a otros en la comunidad. Saludos.

Comment: Donde marco, soy nuevo en stackoverflow?

Comment: Te invito a que pases por aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: ok, gracias amigo